# Fixing "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" using single query

Tags: mysql

I have multiple users querying multiple databases in my app. When one of them receives an error "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" I can do something LIKE this:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE `USER`='trial_505813';
```

then

```
KILL 25685;
```

But can I do something like:

```
KILL (SELECT `ID` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE `USER`='trial_505813')
```

to kill all processes from specified user with one query?

Comment: Are you using MariaDB or MySQL? You used both tags for your question, but these are not the same product.

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB has a `KILL USER <name>` command: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/kill/

MySQL does not implement this feature. You would have to fetch all the process id's for that user and write a loop to kill them one by one.

Example in Python:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='xxxx', database='test')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE USER = %s", ["trial_505813"])
result = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
    cursor.execute(f"KILL {row[0]}")
```

I have to comment that killing queries or threads because of a lock wait timeout seems like a harsh solution. It's likely that you could optimize queries so they don't hold locks too long.

If the query is already optimized, you could be letting a transaction remain uncommitted too long. A transaction holds locks until the transaction is finished. So you need to finish transactions (COMMIT or ROLLBACK) promptly after the query is done.

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.7. I understand that kill process is not a good solution, but sometimes user app hangs up, and locks the database, even after restarting the app. Can you help me with writing a loop for finding and killing user processes?